# Monotouch: WCF Client Example Needed

Tags: .net, wcf, xamarin.ios, slsvcutil

I am trying to create a WCF client to connect to my server using MonoTouch. Since Monotouch doesn't support dynamic code generation I tired using slscvutil.exe to generate the client code. The output I get from that does not compile. It tries to use `ChannelBase` as a generic class `ChannelBase<T>`, but it is not generic. Additionally all examples I can find use `ChannelBase` as a generic class. Does anyone have a sample of a MonoTouch WCF client in .net 4.0? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've not got a sample for you - both the WCF client apps I've built are closed source - but I've successfully followed the steps on http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Application_Fundamentals/Introduction_to_Web_Services to build 2 apps, including using the SLsvcutil tool - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197958%28v=vs.95%29.aspx.

Further, `ChannelBase<T>` is clearly Generic in SL4 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190431%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Is there a sample you can post which shows the error? e.g. a client and service which replicate the error you are seeing.