# Only 'parameters' element in message is supported error in MonoTouch

Tags: wcf, xamarin.ios, wcf-data-services

I get an error Only 'parameters' element in message is supported error in MonoTouch when I try to add a straightforward WCF service as a web reference

Are there any options that I have to set on the service?

Paul

Comment: You should check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214286/monotouch-wcf-client-example-needed - maybe it helps. You will have to use the Silverlight command line utility to generate your service reference.